# Codeigniter xml-rpc issue

Tags: codeigniter, xml-rpc

I encountered a weird issue with CodeIgniter xml-rpc. If some data in the request contains `system (xxx)` it is automatically converted to `system &140;xxx&140;`

It only happens when you have word `system` followed by opening and closing brackets.

For example if I send `Bachelor in Information system (BIS)` it is received as `Bachelor in Information system &140;BIS&141;`

Just wondering if anyone else has ever had this issue or know anything about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is caused by the CodeIgniter XSS filtering which is activated by default. It happens because system() is a command in PHP to execute shell code.

Simple workaround (not recommended): Deactivate it in config.php

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```

Better workaround: Deactivate it on a per-case base in your XML-RPC controller, so in the server part set

```
$this->config->set_item('global_xss_filtering',FALSE);
```

Comment: Yes you are right. Its because of the xss filtering. But it is not governed by `global_xss_filtering` parameter in config file. Even if you make it FALSE, issue still comes. Rather there is a separate `xss_clean` property in Xmlrpc.php which govern this setting. Thanks for your help.